# What will be expected value of smallest element of chosen set

Tags: probability

We are given a set $X = \{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ where $x_i = 2^i$. A sample $S$ (which is a subset of $X$) drawn by selecting each $x_i$ independently with probability $p_i = \frac{1}{2^i}$. What will be the expected value of the smallest number in sample $S$?

Comment: There is a positive probability that $S$ is empty. What is the smallest number in $S$ then?

Comment: It was not mention in problem. Let us consider it 0.

Comment: AP: It relevantly changes the result; if this is a homework problem then you should talk to your instructor about how that case should be treated.  (My inclination would be to have an $x_0=2^0=1$ that is selected with probability $p_0 = \frac{1}{2^0}=1$, essentially considering the inital problem definition an 'off-by-one' error, because that makes things cleanest.)

Comment: @Steven , I agree with you. This is not a homework problem this was some test problem.

Comment: Are you quite sure that "smallest" shouldn't be "largest"?  If the latter then the problem is substantially easier, and @HagenvonEitzen's (previous) solution is right.

Comment: Yeah it was smallest element in set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer $E_n$ depends on $n$, for $n=0$ it is clearly $E_0=0$.
For $n\ge 1$, we have the recursion
$$E_n=1 + \frac12 E_{n-1}$$
because with probability $\frac12$ we have $\min S=2$ and with probability $\frac12$ the result is the same as from taking a sample from $\{x_2,\ldots ,x_n\}=2\cdot\{x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$ and rejecting it with probabiliy $\frac12$. By induction, $E_n=2-2^{1-n}$.

Comment: I found that the probability for $X_i$ to be smallest in S is given as $\frac{1}{2^i}$.

And this is like probability for $X_i$ to be smallest in S=Probability for $X_i$ to be present in S $\times$ Probability for all Elements $X_j \lt X_i$ not present in S.

But my query is why are we not taking probability for $X_i$ to be smallest in S as = Probability for $X_i$ to be present in S $\times$ Probability of all $X_j \gt X_i$ present or not present in S.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1$ is drawn (which happens with probability $\frac{1}{2^1}$), then perforce the smallest number in the sample is $x_1=2^1$.

If $x_1$ is not drawn but $x_2$ is (which happens with probability $(1-\frac{1}{2^1})\frac{1}{2^2}$), then perforce the smallest number in the sample is $x_2=2^2$.

If $x_1,x_2$ are not drawn but $x_3$ is (which happens with probability $(1-\frac{1}{2^1})(1-\frac{1}{2^2})\frac{1}{2^3}$), then perforce the smallest number in the sample is $x_3=2^3$.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I was able to do it but was not able to add it up. It was a test problem, In which there were  1/n , 2 , sqrt(n) and  n . Could you please give something more specific ?